# Google cloud won't let me increase GPU quota until I've used my present quota, which is 0?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-dl-platform

Apparently google will not offer support for free trials, so there is no way to get official help on this.

I am trying to set up a free trial version of google cloud, to run a deep learning project on a cloud GPU. After setting up a project, I wish to add a machine learning VM. I go there, and it tells me I need to increase my GPU quota. However, when I follow the 'change quota' link, I can't change the GPU quota, because I am not using my currently available quota (which is 0) ...

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on what to do? The aim for me was to make a guide for my students who will need this resource in a few days. I got it to work on another google account in summer, but need to go through it again on a fresh account, so I can tell my students what it will look like for them. So, I think I'm familiar with most of the steps, but I haven't seen this "service usage history" error before.

Comment: GPUs are not available for Free Trials. You must first upgrade to a paid account. However, even after upgrading, Google might not approve a GPU quota increase. In other words, you will not have GPU access in a couple of days. If you are an educator with a recognized institution, signup for an education account. https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier https://cloud.google.com/solutions/education

Comment: The message about service history is basically a message that using a resource would exceed your credit line. You consume Google Cloud resources during the month and then pay. GPUs are expensive and have limited availability.

Comment: is this something that changed within the last few months? I am trying to use the 300 USD credits that come with the 'free trial', after having upgraded the account. when I did the same exercise in May, it was not a problem for me to spend the 300 USD on a GPU VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to somehow be related to the fact that I have already used the 300 USD on a different google account. I tried it with a colleague who had not used any paid google product before, and it worked just as it should.
So, somehow, either through my credit card info or something else, google cloud knows about the other account.

Answer (score 0):

Google has [restricted](https://cloud.google.com/free) few products in free trial. You can upgrade the account during the free trial. Both free trial and paid will be running simultaneously but you will be paying only for restricted products which were not available in free trial. .
The GPUs on Compute Engine are no longer in beta and are shown in free trial. But, you can start machine learning in free trial mode as the quota is 0.

However you can try products which are machine learning based like Auto ML, Vision API, Bigquery(Depending on your project and your needs) as per [free tier usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier-usage-limits). Also check out [GPU pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus).

Comment: is this something that changed within the last few months? I am trying to use the 300 USD credits that come with the 'free trial', after having upgraded the account. when I did the same exercise in May, it was not a problem for me to spend the 300 USD on a GPU VM?

Comment: Google has restricted few products in free trial. You can upgrade the account during the free trial. Both free trial and paid will be running simultaneously but you will be paying only for restricted products which were not available in free trial. Please check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade). Hope I have cleared your query.

Comment: This statement is wrong **you cannot upgrade until 300$ credit is consumed**. You can upgrade at any time.